# Handling both JSON and form values in POST request body with unknown values in Golang

Tags: json, go, http, request, http-post

I have a HTTP server and now want to handle POST requests with multiple content types and unknown values. Specifically I want to be able to get the values from the POST request body, both if it's a raw JSON (`application/json`) and also if it is sent from a form (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or even `multipart/form-data`). Also the values are not known in advance, so I can't use a predefined struct to save the data into.

Is there some way to handle both cases simultaneously?

I know that for form values, you use `r.ParseForm()` (or `r.Form` and `r.PostForm`) to get the data and for JSON you would read `r.Body` where `r` is the request object. So if I want to handle both form and raw JSON, do I have to check for the content type and then use the appropriate methods or is there some better way?